# SKScene automatically resumed when dismissing iAd Modal Controller

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, iad, modalviewcontroller

working on the Space Ship tutorial, I have a strange behavior, and I wonder if it comes from a bad implementation or iOS issues (both as it seems).
When the user hits the iAd banner, I pause the view in my scene. This view contains the hud layer (that shows the resume/quit buttons and the game scene).
So far, it works great.
But when the user dismisses the iAd Controller, the scene never receives the touches since it is pause.

If I pause only the game layer, it works fine ... except that all the actions are automatically resumed when dismissing the controller (w/o setting the view.paused = NO of course).

For the record : when the Ad controller is presented, I use the same code I use when the user touches the pause button. I have the same behavior with moving the app to background and back to front.

What should I do then? Is it a bug with my layer organisation, a bug with iOs resuming actions it shouldn't?
Thanks.

Comment: can you subscribe to the dismiss notification?

Comment: it's a delegate, but Yes, it's implemented but there is nothing I can do here as a part of the scene is automatically resumed...